# Install sbt on ubuntu

Tags: scala, debian, ubuntu-12.04, sbt, deb

I have installed sbt on Ubuntu.

```
:~/bin/sbt/bin$ ls
classes    sbt      sbt-launch.jar       target
jansi.jar  sbt.bat  sbt-launch-lib.bash  win-sbt
```

However, whenever I try to launch sbt (from the same directory where sbt is located) it does not work:

```
No command 'sbt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'skt' from package 'latex-sanskrit' (universe)
 Command 'sb2' from package 'scratchbox2' (universe)
 Command 'sbd' from package 'cluster-glue' (main)
 Command 'mbt' from package 'mbt' (universe)
 Command 'sbmt' from package 'atfs' (universe)
 Command 'lbt' from package 'lbt' (universe)
 Command 'st' from package 'suckless-tools' (universe)
 Command 'sb' from package 'lrzsz' (universe)
```

I am new to linux and I have no idea how to tackle this issue.

Comment: to execute a file in the current directory you have to write a "./" in front of the name, or else it will try to search for the executables inside the classpath. So to do that in particular you should have typed "./sbt". That's what was going wrong here, however it's obviously best to follow the other answers below and actually install it.

Comment: I don't see any reason to close this question. sbt is very useful programming tool for scala and maybe it fits the StackOverflow rules.

Comment: Who made the decision to close this question?? Why do you not first consider what would be the alternatives. Superuser is *not* the place. `sbt` does not belong there. This is the correct place - and I am among the persons interested in this question/answer.  I am a server side programmer is that not "on topic" enough?

Comment: This is ridiculous that this question is closed. SBT is a tool for programming.

Comment: Official instructions on installing for Linux are here: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It seems like you installed a zip version of sbt, which is fine. But I suggest you install the native debian package if you are on Ubuntu. That is how I managed to install it on my Ubuntu 12.04. Check it out here:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html
Or simply directly download it from [here](https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.15.deb).

Comment: Yes, the problem was due to the fact that I have installed a zip version and the installation files were somehow "broken".

Comment: FYI: link is broken. Should be this: http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/ I think.

Comment: You can also install sbt by writing the following commands if regular apt-get isn't working:
wget https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.15.deb
sudo dpkg -i  path/to/sbt.deb
sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score 162):

The simplest way of installing SBT on ubuntu is the `deb` package provided by Typesafe.

Run the following shell commands:

1. `wget http://apt.typesafe.com/repo-deb-build-0002.deb`
2. `sudo dpkg -i repo-deb-build-0002.deb`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install sbt`

And you're done !

Comment: Works great! But than I get: 
"Detected sbt version 0.12.2
Cannot find sbt launcher 0.12.2
Please download:
  From  http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar
    To  /home/leo/.sbt/.lib/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar" 
So it's already written what do do. But here for your reference: "  mkdir -p /home/leo/.sbt/.lib/0.12.2/
wget  -O /home/leo/.sbt/.lib/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.12.2/sbt-launch.jar"

Comment: @leo Thanks for the addition. I won't add it to the answer because it's not specific to the question, but it is relevant for all sbt installation using the same `sbt` script.

Comment: what the version of sbt is it?

Comment: @MariusKavansky It installs just a script which allows to run every version of sbt. You'll have to at specify which version you want to use in the file `project/build.properties`. Then you run `sbt` and the script will kick the launcher. Follow the instructions that will appear.

Comment: @RémiM As I answered in the comments above, once you use the method I described to install an sbt launcher, you can choose the actual SBT version in the `project/build.properties` file. I am currently using SBT 13.6 with the proposed method without any trouble.

Comment: That just installed a very old sbt 0.11.3. Any idea how to install the newest?

Comment: Just follow the instructions on the accepted answer, that one installs the latest version.

Comment: @IvanBalashov this installed 0.13.13 for me

Comment: ```Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: D2E3915347209000FA1C06D47CF8D72BE29DF322
E: The repository 'http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: I worked according to https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

Comment: This is dangerous. You should never install packages downloaded through http without checking the signatures or checksums through with ones downloaded through encrypted channel.

Answer (score 13):

> No command `sbt` found

It's saying that `sbt` is not on your path. Try to run `./sbt` from `~/bin/sbt/bin` or wherever the `sbt` executable is to verify that it runs correctly. Also check that you have execute permissions on the `sbt` executable. If this works , then add `~/bin/sbt/bin` to your path and `sbt` should run from anywhere.

See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) about adding a directory to your path.

To verify the [path is set correctly](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm) use the `which` command on LINUX. The output will look something like this:

```
$ which sbt
/usr/bin/sbt
```

Lastly, to verify `sbt` is working try running `sbt -help` or likewise. The output with -help will look something like this:

```
$ sbt -help
Usage: sbt [options]

  -h | -help         print this message
  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative approach, you can save the [SBT Extras](https://raw.github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt) script to a file called sbt.sh and set the permission to executable. Then add this file to your path, or just put it under your ~/bin directory.

The bonus here, is that it will download and use the correct version of SBT depending on your project properties. This is a nice convenience if you tend to compile open source projects that you pull from GitHub and other.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the directory ~/bin/sbt/bin is not in your PATH.

To execute programs or scripts that are in the current directory you need to prefix the command with ./, as in:

```
./sbt
```

This is a security feature in linux, so to prevent overriding of system commands (and other programs) by a malicious party dropping a file in your home directory (for example).  Imagine a script called 'ls' that emails your /etc/passwd file to 3rd party before executing the ls command...  Or one that executes 'rm -rf .'...

That said, unless you need something specific from the latest source code, you're best off doing what paradigmatic said in his post, and install it from the Typesafe repository.