# How to install sbt without gcj-4.5-jre in Ubuntu?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, installation, package, sbt

When I am trying to install `sbt` in Ubuntu  as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711395/install-sbt-on-ubuntu):

```
wget http://apt.typesafe.com/repo-deb-build-0002.deb
sudo dpkg -i repo-deb-build-0002.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

The last command `sudo apt-get install sbt` asks if I want to install `GJI` -- GNU java interpreter.

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcj-4.5-jre gcj-4.5-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  fastjar gcj-4.5-jdk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcj-4.5-jre gcj-4.5-jre-headless sbt
```

I do not want to install it. How can I install an `sbt` package in Ubuntu without `GCJ` ?

Comment: Install either oracle jdk/jre or openjkd/jre

Comment: Oracle JDK is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can go on the sbt website, download it,extract it somewhere in your home directory and add it in the path.

I have it on ~/apps/sbt/ and i added the following in the end of ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/apps/sbt/bin:$PATH
```

I found it the simplest way to achive this because the apt typesafe respository is outdated.