# SBT install failure with aptitude on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: scala, ubuntu, sbt, typesafe

I receive several errors when I attempt to install sbt on Ubuntu via aptitude with the instructions from the scala-sbt homepage:

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

First I get a package validation error and then a segmentation fault.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sbt
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,041 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,224 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  sbt
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received a segmentation fault.
```

EDIT:

I can browse the mirror fine without any cert errors.

Confirming which mirror it's using with apt-cache.

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy sbt
sbt:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.13.7
  Version table:
     0.13.7 0
        500 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages
     0.13.6 0
        500 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages
     0.13.5 0
        500 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages
     0.13.2 0
        500 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages
     0.13.1-0.1-build-001 0
        500 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages
     0.13.0-0.1-build-001 0
        500 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages
     0.12.4-0.1-build-001 0
        500 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/  Packages
```

EDIT 2: I ended up just downloading the package manually and installing it with dpkg.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are related answers which lead me to this solution:

```
wget https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.7.deb
sudo dpkg -i sbt-0.13.7.deb
```

P.S. I think that officially documented way does not work because they didn't provide the public key used by apt to authenticate packages.

P.P.S. After some research I've found that this issue is more related to the apt package, there are many reports about this error at bugs.launchpad.net. So, while it's still an issue that sbt didn't provide public key, but it shouldn't cause this error. I hope canonical will resolve this soon.

Related:

- [Install sbt on ubuntu [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718915/131337)
- [Install Java Scala and SBT on Debian (useless pain in the ass)](https://gist.github.com/samklr/8ca9051d5e1e72a0caf1)

Comment: Yes, this is what I did as well.  I'll accept it as answer, but hopefully somebody from typesafe can pipe in and address the root cause, or update their official docs.

Comment: Thanks @SeanGlover, I agree that typesafe should be aware of this bug and document it or provide a bug-free installation method, yet as I found the problem takes its roots from apt package and affects many other users. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You don't need to run `apt-get update` for this to work

Comment: @DavidWeber, thanks for noticing that, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Manual install is also available:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Also, as a temporary workaround, you could use HTTP repository address instead of HTTPS.
Just open file **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list** and replace

```
deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /
```

with

```
deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /
```