# Cannot build sbt project due to launcher version

Tags: scala, sbt, ubuntu-14.04

I have a SBT projec on Ubuntu 14.04. When I run sbt I get the following message:

```
Detected sbt version sbt.version = 0.13.8
Starting sbt: invoke with -help for other options
Cannot find sbt launcher sbt.version = 0.13.8
Please download: 
  From  http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/sbt.version = 0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar
    To  /home/vagrant/.sbt/.lib/sbt.version/sbt-launch.jar
```

When I try and download from the above url I am met with a 404 response. In fact even the url http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com is giving 404.

Any ideas how I can get the correct sbt version on my system?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711395/install-sbt-on-ubuntu ?

Comment: No, I came across this already. The instructions are clear - download the jar and save it in the specified dir - but the server hosting the jar seems to not be working. I.e. it is returning 404 for all requests

Answer (score 3):

One solution is not to use the package manager at all. Uninstall sbt, and simply use the sbt shell script by Paul Phillips: https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras :

```sh
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt > ~/bin/sbt \
  && chmod 0755 ~/bin/sbt
```

This is quite up-to-date and should have the correct repositories for the launchers.

Answer (score 2):

Your installed sbt version is probably a bit older and still refers to the old repository. 
Typesafe moved to a bintray repository so the new url would be:

https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar

or with alias

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar

`repo.typesafe.com` may be replaced by `repo.lightbend.com` in the future ;)

Reinstalling the sbt run script would probably help, too.

Answer (score 2):

How did you install sbt? 
If you're using sbt-extras you might be hitting [#107](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/pull/107). Try upgrading it to a newer version.

An alternative is to switch to the official version of sbt. See [Installing sbt on Linux](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html):

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```