# Sbt on ubuntu 16.04 installation failure

Tags: sbt, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I am facing a `failed downloads` problem while trying to install `sbt 0.13.13` on `ubuntu 16.04` following the documentation on: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html.

Below, the message log:

[image]

I also tried the answer from `paradigmatic` here: [Install sbt on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711395/install-sbt-on-ubuntu), and: https://askubuntu.com/questions/732092/how-to-install-sbt-in-its-latest-version-in-ubuntu-14-04. Those posts are a little old.
Neverhteless, the official method seems to bug so far.

Anyone faced the same impediments?

Comment: Thanks... I edited my post.

Comment: does https://medium.com/@henricook/solution-to-sun-security-validator-validatorexception-e300dd7dba70#.tk7u7klut help ?

Comment: installing java8 as in the posts solves it for me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you post an answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause and solution is actually provided by https://medium.com/@henricook/solution-to-sun-security-validator-validatorexception-e300dd7dba70#.tk7u7klut. The experimental java9 is to blame. Installing java8 as in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04 will solve it.